# Parsing String in Java using a Pattern

Tags: java, parsing

I am trying parse out 3 pieces of information from a `String`.

Here is my code:

```
text = "H:7 E:7 P:10";
String pattern = "[HEP]:";

Pattern p = Pattern.compile(pattern);

String[] attr = p.split(text);
```

I would like it to return:

```
String[0] = "7"
String[1] = "7"
String[2] = "10"
```

But all I am getting is:

```
String[0] = ""
String[1] = "7 "
String[2] = "7 "
String[3] = "10"
```

Any suggestions?

Comment: Why not just split them by spaces first, then in each index, just search for a specific pattern, in your case the ":" and just get the character/s after that, since it follows the same pattern over and over.

Comment: Is the format always going to have an "H", "E", and "P" in succession?

Comment: Why not just make a regexp finding all numbers?

Comment: I was going to suggest what Andy did. Good thing I refreshed the page! So you parse each string looking for the colon, and insert the result into a Map, where the text before the colon is the Key, and the text after the colon (which you may first convert to an Integer/Double) is the Value.

Comment: @ChaosPandion yes it will always be H, E, P in that order.

Comment: What are the actual parsing rules that you want to implement?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

A not-so-elegant solution I just devised:

```
String text = "H:7 E:7 P:10";
String pattern = "[HEP]:";
text = text.replaceAll(pattern, "");
String[] attr = text.split(" ");
```

Comment: not so elegant, but easy to follow and understand and was the answer that worked.  Thanks.

Answer (score 2):

From the javadoc, http://docs.oracle.com/javase/6/docs/api/java/util/regex/Pattern.html#split(java.lang.CharSequence) :

> The array returned by this method contains **each substring of the input
>   sequence that is terminated by another subsequence that matches this
>   pattern** or is terminated by the end of the input sequence.

You get the empty string first because you have a match at the beginning of the string, it seems.

If I try your code with String text = "A H:7 E:7 P:10" I get indeed:

> A  7  7  10

Hope it helps.

Comment: Yes, the string starts with the pattern. If we substitute the pattern for "," and pretend it's a comma-delimited record, we would have: "H:7 E:7 P:10" --> ",7 ,7 ,10", i.e. this record starts with an empty field.

Answer (score 2):

I would write a full regular expression like the following:

```
Pattern pattern = Pattern.compile("H:(\\d+)\\sE:(\\d+)\\sP:(\\d+)");
Matcher matcher = pattern.matcher("H:7 E:7 P:10");
if (!matcher.matches()) {
    // What to do!!??
}
String hValue = matcher.group(1);
String eValue = matcher.group(2);
String pValue = matcher.group(3);
```

Comment: matcher.group is null; apparently it doesn't find any matches with this code.

Comment: @Justin - Try the latest version. The Java Regex API is really lame.

Comment: if stmt is of no use.  program does not find any matches using the pattern you are supplying.

Comment: @Justin - Looks like I forgot to escape the backslashes.

Answer (score 1):

Basing on your comment I take it that you only want to get the numbers from that string (in a particular order?).

So I would recommend something like this:

```
Pattern p = Pattern.compile("\\d+");
Matcher m = p.matcher("H:7 E:7 P:10");
while(m.find()) {
    System.out.println(m.group());
}
```

Comment: same issues as with ChaosPandion's answer.

Comment: You mean that if the string you pass in is of a different format (has no numbers) then the matcher does not find anything? Well that is pretty obvious and you need to handle it in your code :) Or did you mean something else?

Comment: if i use your code snippet then m.group(0) throws IllegalStateException.